# jquery.each() - "this" vs valueOfElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop, I always thought that `this` was equivalent to `valueOfElement`. Could someone explain the difference?

Example:

```
$.each(object, function(i, val){
    $('body').append('<b>valueOfElement:</b> ' + typeof val + ' - ' +  
    '<b>this: </b>' + typeof this + '<br/>');
});
```

Result:

```
valueOfElement: string - this: object
valueOfElement: boolean - this: object
valueOfElement: object - this: object
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mfqe/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation you linked to :

> The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but
>   Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is
>   a simple string or number value.

All values are embedded in objects when accessed as `this`.

The real reason can be found in this line of [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) :

```
callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
```

You can compare it to

```
(function(){console.log(this)}).call(1);
```

which builds a `Number`, because you can't call a function on something that isn't an object.

From [MDN on the call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

> **thisArg** :
>
> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the
>   method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will
>   be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be
>   boxed.

The only advantages I would see in using `this` instead of `valueOfElement` are :

- simplicity : you don't have to keep in mind the order of arguments given to the callback
- ability to use a function directly on `this` even if `valueOfElement` is of primitive type

Comment: Ok, would it be any advantage to use one over the other? valueOfElement vs this, that is.

Comment: @VisioN I don't seem to be able to write correct English sentences at first try :\

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword will access the element as a JavaScript object. You can get it's value the same way you would any other JavaScript object, or you can wrap it (`$(this)`) to make it into a jQuery object.