# Why doesn't $.each() iterate through every item?

Tags: javascript, iteration, jquery

I have the following markup containing 10 `pre` elements with the class `indent`:

```
​<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>
<pre class="indent"></pre>​
```

I'm using the following jQuery `.each()` function to iterate through each element:

```
​$(function(){    
    $.each(".indent", function(index){
       alert(index); 
    });    
});​
```

I would expect to see 10 alerts, however I only see 7

[**-- See Fiddle --**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nzw9/)

---

However, this works as expected with `$(".indent").each()`:

```
$(function(){    
    $(".indent").each(function(index){
       alert(index); 
    });    
});​
```

[**-- See Fiddle --**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nzw9/)

---

Looking at the `$.each()` documentation, I understand theres a difference:

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.

But I don't understand why in this instance, it doesn't iterate through all elements.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert`, you'll get better data for debugging.

Comment: $.each(".indent") doesn't interate over .indent objects. It interates on ".indent" string.

Comment: just a side note: better use console.log instead of alert. much better for testing, it is a pain to close all those popups.

Comment: @luschn Thanks, earlier versions did use `console.log()`, but after hours of head scratching, and double-guessing, every bit of code had to be changed in case :P

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
$.each(".indent", function(index){
```

doesn't iterate over the elements of `$('.indent')` but over the `".indent"` string whose length is 7 chars.

See [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

---

**A more detailed explanation based on [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) :**

jQuery first checks if the first parameter, `obj` (here your string), has a `length` :

```
var ...
        length = obj.length,
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction( obj );
```

Your string having a `length` (and not being a function), `isObj` is `false`.

In this case, the following code is executed :

```
for ( ; i < length; ) {
    if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

So, given the function `f`, the following code

```
$.each(".indent", f);
```

is equivalent to

```
for (var i=0; i<".indent".length; i++) {
    var letter = ".indent"[i];
    f.call(letter, i, letter);
}
```

(you can log the letters using `var f = function(i,v){console.log(v)};` or be reminded one of the subtleties of `call` using `var f = function(){console.log(this)};`)

Comment: I've seen 9 upvotes for a JS addition function in under a minute, but 17 for an `.each()`... have to upvote just for fun :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I also had this kind of issue recently.

Answer (score 38):

You are iterating through the string, you should pass an object or an array to `$.each` method:

```
$(function(){    
    $.each($(".indent"), function(index){
       alert(index);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 22):

$.each iterates over a collection of data. Since you pass a String that have 7 chars, it will iterate for each char. See the example of use:

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `value` argument...  I have no idea why JQuery decided to reverse the two, generally you want `value` more often than `index`

Comment: @Izkata for the value you usually use `this` (well, [not always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123360/jquery-each-this-vs-valueofelement)). That's why `index` is the most useful parameter and so the first one.