# How to select dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sounds trivial but it's not (to me at least).

I know that when trying to bind an event to dynamic content you must use `.on()`, but how can I select the element and run general operations on them?

I have a table with dynamic rows, inside the row i have 1 anchor tags on some td, which i've given the class `pricelist_balloon`.

How can i select it? I've tried :

```
$.each('.pricelist_balloon',function() {});
$('.pricelist_balloon').each(function() {});
$('#parent_div .pricelist_balloon').each(function() {});
$('#parent_div').each('.pricelist_balloon', function() {});
```

But none seem to work. How can i do this?

Comment: Be careful with `$.each('.pricelist_balloon'`. [It doesn't do what you think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648515/why-doesnt-each-iterate-through-every-item).

Comment: Should work ?? `$('#parent_div .pricelist_balloon').each(function() {});`

Comment: It doesn't as those elements are generated using js. @JonathandeM. that's the first one ive tried

Comment: You want to have code automatically executed when an element is inserted ?

Comment: Any JS error in console?

Comment: No errors and @dystroy no i want to iterate them at later point in code not when generated

Comment: `$('#parent_div .pricelist_balloon').each(function() {});` should work. I suggest you to put a breakpoint at the start of the function and debug. If it doesn't work, log what's inside `$('#parent_div .pricelist_balloon')`.

Comment: Ya i realized the problem, thank you dystroy!

Comment: @eric.itzhak You're welcome. And thanks to you to have told what the problem was. It's always painful when askers just delete their question without regards to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the selector `$('#parent_div .pricelist_balloon').each(function() {});`

Seemed to work, could be others are working too but my problem was that i generated my content in a function called in an AJAX success so at time i was running this code the elements weren't generated yet.

Thanks to all the helpers.