# Why would jquery's .each() callback have the indexInArray as the first argument instead of valueOfElement?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, jquery

A strange question, but every time I use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) I wonder why the `indexInArray` is the first argument and not the second (the second currently being the value itself), like the native `array.forEach()`?

There is [an identical, but unanswered question](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#comment-125736511) with a decent number of upvotes on the API docs for `.each()` too!

More often than not, I find code that "acts on" the value and not the index, resulting in an unused variable in the body of the function (which makes js(h|l)int complain, with good reason in my opinion). So, why isn't the value the first argument?

Is this a hangover from an poorly thought out implementation in an earlier version, or is there a good reason for this?

Comment: It's their API, they can make it return whatever they want. At this point, backwards compatibility prevents anything from being changed.

Comment: Yeah I totally get that, I just wondered what the reasoning was behind the decision in the first instance.

Comment: In most cases a `while` or `for` loop will be faster than either of these methods, so if you don't like them, consider if you really need them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the first argument of `foreach`, the value, is less needed in `$.each` as jQuery provides it as `this`.

Thus, the index appears to be more often useful. This is a good reason.

I write "appears", because this doesn't come without perils : `this` isn't exactly the same as the value when the value is of primitive type : in this case the value is wrapped as an object.

Why is it dangerous ?

Here's why :

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(v) {
    if (v===2) console.log('found!');
});
```

Output in the console :

```
found!
```

Now with jQuery :

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function() {
    if (this===2) console.log('found!');
});
```

What’s the output ?

Nothing.

(note that I detail the implementation leading to this in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123360/jquery-each-this-vs-valueofelement).)

Today, with people being more and more used to the standard javascript function, it might be thought that having the other order would have been better (that was the choice of [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#each)). The reason to provide the index first was good, but maybe not good enough. But maybe it doesn't really matter as we probably won't continue using `$.each` now that `foreach` is generally available (at least for arrays).

Comment: but `this` behaves quite differently (since it encapsulates whatever the value is in an object). Also, I find myself using `jQuery.each` with `jQuery.proxy` around the callback a lot too, so `this` is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Re: "Today, with people being more and more used to the standard javascript function, it might be thought that having the other order would have been better (that was the choice of Underscore.js)." - mootools does the same.